# Php multiple data insertion with textarea

Tags: php, mysql

I have 500+ user:pass and i want add all data with textarea.

Example ;

user:pass
user:pass
user:pass

I use the following codes to add users individually ;

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users SET user = ?, pass = ?");
$insert = $query->execute(array($username, $password));
```

How can I make this to add multiple data  `user = username : pass = password`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Are you trying to insert multiple rows at the same time?

Comment: yes i solved thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `explode` to split your string with a separator for example if you have a string like this

```
john:1234 mario:465789
```

after `explode` it will be like this

```php
$data = explode(' ', $_POST['textarea']);
print_r($data);

/*
[
 'john:1234',
 'mario:465789'
]
*/
```

after that, you could `explode` it one more time from the ':' so you could try something like this

```php
$data = $_POST['textarea'];
$data = explode(' ', $data);

foreach($data as $record){
   $user = explode(':', $record);
   
   $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users SET user = ?, pass = ?");
   $insert = $query->execute(array($user[0], sha1($user[1])));
}
```

> another thing it is so dangerous to save `password` as plain text so I just add `sha1` to add some level of security for hashing the password

### Another solution

you could also use `regex` to be more efficient like this

```php
$data = $_POST['textarea'];

preg_match_all('/(\S+:\S+)/m', $data, $matches);

foreach($matches as $record){
   $user = explode(':', $record);

   $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users SET user = ?, pass = ?");
   $insert = $query->execute(array($user[0], sha1($user[1])));
}
```

Comment: thanks that's working but not properly added to database. => https://prnt.sc/12hqx5n

Comment: that is because your data don't have the same pattern

Comment: check the answer again i add another better solution